# connecting to sharepoint oniline using Powershell : Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-clientobject

Hi I am trying to connect to sharepoint online and publish calender using the data from a SQL Table and I am getting the following exception , please advise.The same code works fine with slight modification on a on prem sharepoint server I have added sharepointonline for the authentication but it is failing with the error.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile ("C:\MOSSLibrary\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\MOSSLibrary\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll") | Out-Null 
$username = "XXXXXX"
$url = "XXXXXX"


$pass= cat C:\text.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username,$Pass)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds

$web = $Context.Web
$Context.Load($web)
$Context.Load($splist)
$splist = $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle("XXXX")

$ItemCreateInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation

####Some Data coming from SQL Server DB into $table########

$table = $result.Tables[0];

foreach ($row in $table)
{

Write-Host $row.Item("changetitle") $row.Item("status");

$Item1 =  $splist.AddItem($ItemCreateInfo)
$Item1["Title"] = "test"
Write-host $date    
$Item1.Update()
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

**Exception**

> New-Object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate
>   constructor for type Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.   At
>   C:\MOSSLibrary\testingpublish.ps1:15 char:12  + $Context = New-Object
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site ...   +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>         + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
>         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
>     The property 'Credentials' cannot be found on this object. Verify
>   that the property exists and can be set.  At
>   C:\MOSSLibrary\testingpublish.ps1:17 char:1   + $Context.Credentials =
>   $Creds    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>         + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound       You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.   At
>   C:\MOSSLibrary\testingpublish.ps1:20 char:1   + $Context.Load($web)   +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>         + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull     You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.   At
>   C:\MOSSLibrary\testingpublish.ps1:21 char:1   + $Context.Load($splist)
>     + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>         + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull    You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.   At
>   C:\MOSSLibrary\testingpublish.ps1:22 char:1   + $splist =
>   $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle("XXXXXXX")  +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>         + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Answer (score 1):

It seems Assemblies are not loading correctly.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile ("C:\MOSSLibrary\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\MOSSLibrary\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll") | Out-Null
```

Instead of above, try following

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\MOSSLibrary\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\MOSSLibrary\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
```

**PS:** Make sure that `C:\MOSSLibrary\` contains following two `.dll`'s

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
```